# Possibility to Display Most used Words?

Tags: statistics

For my blog i want to determine which words are the most used ones over a period of time and from all posts.
I was searching for a plugin but all i got were plugins for overall stats.

Comment: the most popular words are "the" and "and" there is no reason to write a software for it ;)

Comment:   not the most helpful comment but you made me smile this morning

Comment: lol, glad to do that, the longer form of that comment is that you first need to define what is it exactly what you want to count, as it is not that obvious when you think more about it, for example are shop and shops two different words?

Comment: Also: Do you want to count post titles, body text, …?

Comment: I was looking for the same. I found one that gives you the top 20 keywords. But it seems to be not supported anymore since 2016. https://wordpress.org/plugins/word-stats/ no joy...

Comment: Several years later...I was looking for this exact plugin albeit for a different reason. I am currently attempting to learn Thai, but am frustrated by my inability to express exactly what I mean. Learning a new language requires one to be okay with communicating only a rough approximation of what is truly  meant (at least at first). Because I have a blog that I had been working on for several years and over a hundred posts, I thought: what if I could figure out which words I tend to use more often and then learn those Thai analogs? My own 'top 1000 most used words' so to speak.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is just to put down a kind of roadmap. I think the question touches some machine learning concepts, you used the right "**statistics**" tag. You need to build a *dictionary plugin* learning from your new posts. Probably doing something like:

- Manually create a first **json filter dataset** of most used words in your language (i.g. https://1000mostcommonwords.com/1000-most-common-english-words/). I didn't find an API for it. It would filter out all the words considered or which you consider irrelevant (like prepositions, pronouns, etc).
- Write a function which process all the existing posts and export the content of your interest (description, titles, etc) in **a second json dataset**. You already have the `post_meta`s to exploit, as database source. Remember to assign each content to the `post_id` because you'll need to handle updates or removals.
- Create a function which updates that json on new post updated or published.
- Define a gate comparing the previous **2 json sources**, filtering out words and generating **a new final json file** to parse. You can use a declarative approach with `array_map` or `array_filter` built-in functions.
- Finally, build a logic to count each word occurrence, store in a new database table and display it in a dashboard page.

I guess the parsing activity will become quite intense after a while, if the blog gets rich of contents and you often update your filter dataset. Let's have a look also to these library which could help:

- Machine learning library for php https://php-ml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/
- Event-driven, non-blocking I/O with PHP https://github.com/reactphp/react

Have fun and please share the outcome.